# How to print a form in delphi

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-xe

I want to print a form in delphi and I'm not sure how to go about it. I've tried fiddling with the Print Dialog but I can't get it to print anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only problem I'm having is that it prints a portrait where as I want it to be in landscape. I have tried 'printer.orientation.poLandscape' and nothing changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply call the [`Print`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Print) method of `TForm`. Use the [`PrintScale`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PrintScale) property for extra control in how the printing is scaled.

The print dialog, `TPrintDialog` simply shows the standard system dialog for printing. This allows the user to select a printer, change its properties, select a print range, a number of copies, whether to collate, and so on. When the dialog returns, you can read that information and act accordingly. In other words, `TPrintDialog` allows you to retrieve some choices from the user, but does not perform any printing. You must still perform the actual printing, allowing for those choices.

Your code might therefore look like this:

```
if PrintDialog.Execute then
begin
  // account for any user choices, reading from PrintDialog properties
  PrintScale := ...;
  for i := 1 to PrintDialog.Copies do
    Print;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only problem I'm having is that it prints a portrait where as I want it to be in landscape. I have tried 'printer.orientation.poLandscape' and nothing changes.

Comment: Works fine here. I wonder if your print dialog is setting the orientation. Anyway, that's now a different problem, unrelated to the question you originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can print your form:

```
procedure TForm1.CopiarTexto1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PrintDialog1.Execute then
    print;
end;
```